# Listbox field created in lotus notes takes too much space on the web

Tags: listbox, width, lotus-notes

I have a Listbox field and the choices are very big. Some of them occupy close to two lines, on the notes it looks fine as it just shows up as a rectangular box with scroll bars at the bottom and the side. 
But on the web, the choices (the one's that are too big) occupy the entire width of the web page and each time we have to scroll down, we should move to the extreme right of the screen and scroll down. Is there a way to address this problem

Comment: Please review the generated HTML- Code for this part of your website (and post it here), there should be a hint, why it is so big

Comment: The choices which I have entered in the notes Dialog list field (of which few are very long) are coming within the <textarea> tag. In notes client, the same field has both horizontal and vertical scrolling bars, so that we can scroll to the right to see the text of the choices that are big. But on the web, as the text of the choice becomes bigger, the web page's width increases, so we will have to go to the extreme right to vertically scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases for your long listbox choice values. Usually aliases are used to assign shorter stored values to longer keyword choices, but there's no reason you cant do it in reverse, like this:

```
Choice one is an okay length
Choice two|Choice two is an unreasonably long value that ruins the display on the web
Choice three is also an okay length
Choice four|Choice four is a ridiculously long value that totally blows away the display on the web
Choice five|Choice five is a long and winding road that leads to your door
```

When formatted this way, Notes & Domino will notice the | character in any keyword value and display only what's on the left, but if it is selected the stored value will be what's on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS style to the element in the HTML Attribute section:

```
"style=\"width:300px; height:200px;\""
```

But then the trailing stuff is not shown. Perhaps there are other rules you can apply that will make the content within the control wrap...